# Convert file to ArrayBuffer in javascript

Tags: javascript, filereader, arraybuffer

I'm trying to follow [this](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/media-source.html) example about media source extensions.

I have a webm file at a given URL, and I want to append it to my video tag.

My code is:

```
 Template.video.events({
   'click button': function () {
     var ms = new MediaSource();

     var video = document.querySelector('video');
     video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(ms);

     ms.addEventListener('sourceopen', function(e) {

       var sourceBuffer = ms.addSourceBuffer('video/webm; codecs="vorbis,vp8"');
       var reader = new FileReader();
       var file = File("video/movie.webm");
       var chunck = reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
       sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(chunck);

     }, false);

   }
 });
```

How can transform the webm at the given URL in a arraybuffer so I can feed it to appendBuffer?

Comment: `readAsArrayBuffer` is asynchronous, it doesn't return anything! You  have to use another callback!

Comment: ok now I get it better, I will try to rewrite it.